# System Authenticated Redirection - redirecting to login page over and over

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, content, landing-page, microsites

I'm trying to set up a 'System Authenticated Redirection' microsite in Marketing Cloud.

Even though I'm logged in, it keeps redirecting me to the login page. I enter my details over and over again, but never get anywhere.

I raised a ticket and the support tech told me that it would not work if I am already logged in in the same browser, which seems totally ridiculous.

Unfortunately I've argued the point several times with a Marketing Cloud support tech when they've provided a response I thought was unsatisfactory or downright false, and have on most occasions subsequently been proved right, so I wonder if this is one of those times.

Having said that, I tried accessing the page in a different browser and session and I still had the same problem.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?